# What is the plural for "Egg in a hole"?

Tags: phrases, irregular-plurals

Does two orders of "egg in a hole" become two "eggs in holes" or two "egg in a holes"?
Thank you.

Comment: Stay with "two orders of egg in a hole" to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: What about toad in a hole? Would that become 2,3,4 _toads_ in a hole? Or is it 2,3,4 toad in a _holes_?

Comment: Is an egg in a hole any different than a pudding in the oven, a pig in a poke, a finger in the pie, a dog in a manger, or a hole in one? What sort of regionalism is this?

Comment: @tchrist Things get really weird when _hole in one_ starts being pluralised as _hole in many_.

Comment: Photo at https://img.thrfun.com/img/012/752/egg_toast_l.jpg

Comment: @k1eran who knew! The [toad in the hole](https://www.bbc.com/food/recipes/toad_in_the_hole_with_86283) has metamorphosized into an egg (?). Which came first, the egg or the frog? Why sausages are called toads, I'll never know. It's a crazy language :)

Comment: If you get two orders, are there not two holes with an egg in each hole?  Then of course "hole" should be plural.  Perhaps "Two eggs in holes".

Comment: The last time I got involved in this kind of thing, we received 4 plates, each containing 2 eggs. For 2 people. In Istanbul.

Comment: ‘Two orders of egg in a hole’ is what I suggest, same as @weather vane. Don’t start any discussion on ‘how many eggs in a portion’. It will only confuse them. And get them to show you what they wrote down. Ha!

Comment: In British fish and chip shops it's traditional to order multiple portions of fish and chips as "fish and chips twice/ three times/ four times" and so on. How about "Egg in a hole twice? "

Answer (score 6):

Any one of these is arguably fine:

***eggs in a hole***
***eggs in holes***
***egg-in-a-holes,***

where the last one must include the hyphens.

*Egg in a hole* is the name of a dish. Typically, this is a fried egg that is dropped into a hole that was cut into a piece of toast. For a typical recipe, see [here](https://www.eggs.ca/recipes/eggs-in-a-hole). That website says that *toad in a hole* is an alternative name. There is also *toad in **the** hole*, which apparently has a sausage instead of an egg (see [here](https://www.bbc.com/food/recipes/toad_in_the_hole_with_86283)).

**Discussion**

First, let's see how ***pig in a blanket*** is pluralized. (*Pig in a blanket* is a popular finger food, typically a hot dog served in a wrapper of baked dough. For a typical recipe, see [here](https://www.tasteofhome.com/recipes/pigs-in-a-blanket/).)

***Pig in a blanket*: dictionaries**

According to both the *OED* and [*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pig%20in%20a%20blanket), either *pigs in a blanket* or *pigs in blankets* is fine. [*Oxford Dictionaries*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/pigs_in_a_blanket) has it as *pigs in a blanket*; [*Collins*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pigs-in-blankets) and [*Macmillan*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pigs-in-blankets) as *pigs in blankets*.

***Pig in a blanket*: google books Ngram**

While there are some false positives where *pigs in a blanket* is used in its literal meaning (e.g. [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=PhtArgEACAAJ&dq=%22pigs+in+a+blanket%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-lJK4wobgAhXyV98KHZLGDSUQ6AEIOjAC)), looking through google books, it seems that an overwhelming majority of hits for it (and there are [many](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&biw=1696&bih=827&tbm=bks&ei=TMpJXKj5IIzYtQWt_qWYAg&q=%22pigs+in+a+blanket%22&oq=%22pigs+in+a+blanket%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i299k1.338778.340617.0.341095.3.3.0.0.0.0.186.253.1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.2.253....0.V2vfGU09420)) does correspond to the name of the dish. Furthermore, for *pigs in blankets* I was unable to find it used in any other context except as the name of the dish. Thus an Ngram comparing these two is probably reliable, and it says that *pigs in a blanket* is about twice as common as *pigs in blankets* (see [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pigs+in+a+blanket%2Cpigs+in+blankets&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpigs%20in%20a%20blanket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpigs%20in%20blankets%3B%2Cc0)).

Unfortunately, the Ngram viewer refuses to search for [*pig-in-a-blankets*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pig-in-a-blankets&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=) and finds no hits for [*pig in a blankets*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pig+in+a+blankets&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=).

***Pig in a blanket*: google books**

Currently there are three occurences of *pig-in-a-blankets*: [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=6U5jCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA139&dq=%22pig-in-a-blankets%22&pg=PA139#v=onepage&q=%22pig-in-a-blankets%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=80oMOSzxVlkC&lpg=PA52&dq=%22pig-in-a-blankets%22&pg=PA52#v=onepage&q=%22pig-in-a-blankets%22&f=false), and [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=RvlaAAAAMAAJ&q=%22pig-in-a-blankets%22&dq=%22pig-in-a-blankets%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ8a-e0YbgAhXPs1kKHYxtAXcQ6AEIQjAE).

***Pig in a blanket*: Conclusion**

Both *pigs in a blanket* or *pigs in blankets* is fine, though the former is about twice more common. A few sources use *pig-in-a-blankets* (always hyphenated), but this is quite rare in comparison with the other two.

***Egg in a hole*: dictionaries**

Unfortunately, it seems that no dictionary has an entry for *egg in a hole* at the present time.

***Egg in a hole*: google books Ngram**

Looking through google books for *eggs in a hole* and *eggs in holes*, it seems that an overwhelming majority of hits use the literal meaning of these phrases, like

*The female turtle lays **eggs in a hole** she digs on a particular nesting beach.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=cbUAxUCtHWMC&lpg=PA4&dq=%22eggs%20in%20a%20hole%22&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q=%22eggs%20in%20a%20hole%22&f=false)
 
*Mr. Todd did you ever try packing **eggs in holes** bored through boards and then laced in barrels and then turn them occasionally until the time they are sold?* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=utJBAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22eggs%20in%20holes%22%20recipe&pg=PA77#v=onepage&q=%22eggs%20in%20holes%22%20recipe&f=false)

Thus the Ngram is not really useful in this case: one really needs to look at the context of how a search-string match appears in the source. In addition, just like we saw above for *pig-in-a-blankets/pig in a blankets*, the Ngram viewer refuses to search for *egg-in-a-holes* [(here)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=egg-in-a-holes&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=) and finds no hits for *egg in a holes* [(here)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=egg+in+a+holes&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=).

***Egg in a hole*: google books**

First of all, there were **three** hits for *egg-in-a-holes*, always hyphenated: [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=mmckDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA109&dq=%22egg%20in%20a%20holes%22&pg=PA109#v=onepage&q=%22egg%20in%20a%20holes%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=WT24WBeP5NwC&lpg=PA56&dq=%22egg%20in%20a%20holes%22&pg=PA56#v=onepage&q=%22egg%20in%20a%20holes%22&f=false), and [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=6RlUAAAAMAAJ&q=%22egg+in+a+holes%22&dq=%22egg+in+a+holes%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS476U04bgAhXiq1QKHdcIDRAQ6AEINTAC).

In order to try to filter out the irrelevant hits for the other two possibilities, we can try adding *recipe* to the search.

There is one hit for [*"eggs in a hole" recipe*](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&tbm=bks&ei=dYNIXNWQMKHv_QaPipnoBQ&q=%22eggs+in+a+hole%22+recipe&oq=%22eggs+in+a+hole%22+recipe&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i299k1.62929.62929.0.63413.1.1.0.0.0.0.87.87.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.87....0.KmWONHZoyDk):

*With a few children assisting at a time, prepare **"Eggs in a Hole."*** [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=rBNXxJZmuOUC&lpg=PA102&dq=%22eggs%20in%20a%20hole%22%20recipe&pg=PA102#v=onepage&q=%22eggs%20in%20a%20hole%22%20recipe&f=false)

There is also

*Extra-coconutty **eggs-in-a-hole*** [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=Fe1RCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA168&dq=%22eggs%20in%20a%20hole%22%20recipe&pg=PA168#v=onepage&q=%22eggs%20in%20a%20hole%22%20recipe&f=false),

but this is probably a different dish than the one you have in mind.

A search for [*"eggs in holes" recipe*](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&tbm=bks&ei=3oFIXKK3IdOR0PEP846vqAI&q=%22eggs+in+holes%22+recipe&oq=%22eggs+in+holes%22+recipe&gs_l=psy-ab.12...51615.54001.0.56708.3.3.0.0.0.0.99.247.3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.98...33i10k1.0._q5Fu08KlWA) returned no *relevant* hits.

***Egg in a hole*: the internet at large**

Because of the low rate of hits on google books, we may consider the desperate step of trying to glean how popular the various versions are on the web in general. For what it's worth, having superficially scanned the results of searches for ['"eggs in a hole" recipe'](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&client=firefox-b-1&ei=N9tJXICcLqXC5OUP8bK3yAI&q=%22eggs+in+a+hole%22+recipe&oq=%22eggs+in+a+hole%22+recipe&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i5i30l2.225567.233162..234614...0.0..0.378.923.7j3-1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j33i10.tuscA7cRRmg), ['"eggs in holes" recipe'](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&client=firefox-b-1&ei=I9xJXNeHPPuw5OUP4ee08AI&q=%22eggs+in+holes%22+recipe&oq=%22eggs+in+holes%22+recipe&gs_l=psy-ab.3...10315.12224..12711...0.0..1.419.703.1j0j1j0j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i7i30j0i7i5i30j0i8i30.NCR6IO7_jZk), and ['"egg-in-a-holes" recipe'](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&client=firefox-b-1&ei=DttJXNGPGaGl5OUP0-M1&q=%22egg-in-a-holes%22+recipe&oq=%22egg-in-a-holes%22+recipe&gs_l=psy-ab.3...31965.37926..39870...0.0..0.320.1037.3j2j1j1......0....1..gws-wiz.4e1bmlP_qZU), it seems to me that 1. all three are represented, and 2. *eggs in a hole* is the most popular, followed by *eggs in holes*.

**Conclusion**

An analogy with how *pig in a blanket* is pluralized would suggest that *eggs in a hole* and *eggs in holes* are both fine, while *egg-in-a-holes* is only marginally so. However, so far there seem to be comparably more hits in published literature for *egg-in-a-holes* than for either of the other two. The overall hit rate is very small, on the order of 1-3 hits, so the statistics are not very strong. Perhaps from this we can tentatively conclude that, relative to their respective alternatives, *egg-in-a-holes* is more acceptable that *pig-in-a-blankets*. Finally, the results of a search of the internet at large seem to be consistent with the claim that all three are acceptable, with *eggs in a hole* being the most popular, followed by *eggs in holes*.

Answer (score 3):

It's about what you want to convey.

> Eggs in a hole

indicates there is more than one egg, and they're all in one hole.

> Egg in a holes

doesn't work at all, because you have an article and noun disagreement.

> Egg in holes

indicates there's one egg, and it's in a bunch of different holes.  Either the egg has somehow learned how to be multiple places at once, or, more likely, it's in a bunch of different pieces.

> Eggs in holes

says there's a bunch of eggs, and they're in a bunch of different holes.  It's unclear if there are more eggs than holes, or more holes than eggs, or if it's a one to one relationship.  It could be that some holes have multiple eggs, while others have bits of an egg spread between them.

Edit: while ordering off of a menu, I'd probably go with

> Two orders of eggs in holes.

One would presume that

- multiple instances of a dish called 'an egg in a hole' would each come with their own hole
- the wait staff doesn't care about your word usage, but maximizing the plurality won't go wrong.

Comment: Please consider this from the _register_ of an over-worked waitress (or waiter) in a greasy-spoon...they would economize on words to preserve clarity. So "egg in a holes" would possibly be appropriate. ...like egg-in-a-holes.

Comment: I'm uncertain how 'egg in a holes' would be easier than 'eggs in holes'.  But, that said, I'm not one to pick nits with the word choices of tired people.

Comment: @Cascabel So what do you charge for eggs in a ... oh, that register. (Added to garden path collection.)

Comment: @Cascabel That’s worth turning into an answer. In restaurant lingo, one can have two *waters*, three *egg-in-a-holes*, and even five *buffets* (referring to the diners’ choices and not to duplicate food stations). Retail in general and restaurants in particular tend to pluralise items by treating them as monolithic terms regardless of the dictates of linguistics finery.

Answer (score 3):

I’d order *two egg-in-a-holes*.

It seems, to me, unpretentious and clear, especially if you treat *egg-in-a-hole* as a monolithic thing.

---

EDIT: An earlier version of this answer used some examples were not exactly right so they’re now deleted. Just mentioning this so that the comments below make sense.

Comment: A cat o nine tails is a nine-tailed whip.  There are multiple tails, with one central body.  Your link even said that.  The plurality is in the tails, so of course the tails are plural.  I do, admittedly, understand that link to also say if I had two of them, I would have two cat o nine tails, rather than two cats o nine tails, but that seems confusing to me.

Comment: @EdGrimm I meant two nine-tailed whips. I’ve reworded the answer and added a second (hopefully better) example.

Comment: I would also naturally have said two cats-o’-nine-tails (as well as two eggs-in-a-hole), akin to two mothers-in-law. But I’m not sure I’d really even notice it if any of those were treated as a single unit either. On the other hand, the plural of _son of a bitch_ is definitely neither _sons-of-a-bitch_ or _son of a bitches_, and I’m certain I **would** notice either of those even in casual conversation.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think *pig in a blanket* is a good model. I put that in my answer, below.

Comment: @linguisticturn  & JanusBahsJacquet I admit you have a strong case. Though I think the environment would affect which option is used. For example, in my local fish&chip shop, customers call a portion of chips “a chip” and two portions is called “two chips”. I suspect if egg-in-the-hole was added to the menu, most customers would just add the ‘s’ to make it plural. I realise my answer is subjective and as mush personal preference as anything else.

Comment: @k1eran I'm more used to "a chip*s*" for a portion (especially as it would normally be "a small chips"). Currently in SW England, but I've eaten plenty of chips in London and Manchester

Comment: The plural *cats-o'nine-tails* was used [fairly often](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&biw=1420&bih=730&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1800%2Ccd_max%3A1899&tbm=bks&ei=L7xJXN2LJdCzggfxvrfYBQ&q=%22cats+o+nine%22&oq=%22cats+o+nine%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...10091.10091.0.10583.1.1.0.0.0.0.67.67.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.MSUfQVM_aZ8) in the 19th century. And *cul-de-sac* is a French word, which people who don't know French wouldn't know how to pluralize properly (and *culs-de-sac* is pronounced the same as *cul-de-sac* in French, so the *culs* spelling is misleading).

Comment: I've changed my mind (and my answer), and now I think that *pig-in-a-holes* may be more acceptable than I'd originally thought. The reason is that I found three hits for it on google books, whereas so far I only have one verified hit for any of the alternatives. Nevertheless, I still think that the analogy to *pig in a blanket* should be given lots of weight. Thus I now say all three possibilities are probably fine.